# porque no me funciona el hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventos, hover

capaz alguien sabe porque no me funciona el hover, en este código, algo muy sencillo no me estaría saliendo cuando otras veces sale a la primera, no es mucha ciencia, pero de verdad que la estoy sufriendo, lo intente incluso desde js con un evento mouseover mouseout, incluso utilice mouseleave que he visto en vídeos que también se puede utilizar.. solo me dice que existe el hover cuando le doy tilde a las reglas de hover en la consola, pero no me funciona, si alguien me puede dar una mano, sera bienvenida, les paso fotos del código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código:

```
.gifs-12-conteiner {
  width: 260px;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 311px;
  grid-column-gap: 29px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  &:hover {
    background: #572ee5;
    opacity: 0.7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5 #572ee5;
  }
  .gifs12 {
    width: 260px;
    height: 200px;
    &:hover {
      background: #572ee5;
      opacity: 0.7;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5 #572ee5;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Agrega tu codigo como texto, no como foto.

Comment: .gifs-12-conteiner {
    width: 260px;
    height: 200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 311px;
    grid-column-gap: 29px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    &:hover {
      background: #572EE5;
      opacity: 0.7;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5 #572ee5;
      }
      .gifs12 {
        width: 260px;
        height: 200px;
        &:hover {
          background: #572EE5;
          opacity: 0.7;
          box-shadow: 0 0 5 #572ee5;
        }
      }
  }

Comment: no sabria como ponerlo como formato de codigo, es mi primera pregunta :\

Comment: Edita la pregunta y ponlo alli,  también coloca el html del contenedor

Comment: a la seccion la tengo creada dinamicamente desde js.. le di una clase para poder agregarle los estilos desde css

Comment: El CSS funciona, algo debe pasar al crear dinamicamente desde el js, supongo, porque compilado el css funciona correctamente, solamente coloca los px al 5 en el box shadow

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/386439/edit) tu pregunta para que puedas incluir el código que agregaste en los comentarios. Para convertir un texto en formato de código, seleccionalo y presiona **ctrl+k**. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: es muy raro lo que pasa, porque inlcuso no me anda tampoco desde js, como te comento, utilice un evento mouseover y mouseout y tampoco funciona..

Comment: Hace falta la parte del código Html que contiene los elementos a los que se asigna la clase `.gifs12` y, a primera vista los estilos *parecen* mal formados (puedo estar equivocado por ignorancia): la clase `.gifs12` está anidada dentro del bloque de atributos de `.gifs-12-conteiner{... .gifs12{...} }` saca su declaración del interior de ese bloque y ponla luego de cerrar la llave `}` final de modo que quede así: `.gifs-12-conteiner{...} .gifs12{...}`